# 'sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error' while creating a table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, syntax-error, operationalerror

I am trying to make a stock program for my neighborhood and, I am trying to run this code:

```
def create_tables():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(cod INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, bar_code INTEGER, '\
              'descr VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, quant_stock REAL, type_un TEXT, cost_un REAL, value_un REAL NOT NULL, fab_date TEXT, '\
              'due_date TEXT)')

    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sells(cod INTEGER NOT NULL, bar_code INTEGER, '\
              'descr TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value_un REAL NOT NULL, type_un TEXT, quant_stock REAL NOT NULL, '\
              'tot_value REAL NOT NULL, sell_date TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (cod) REFERENCES products(cod)')

    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchase(cod INTEGER FOREIGN KEY, bar_code INTEGER, '\
              'descr TEXT NOT NULL, cost_un REAL, type_un TEXT, pur_quant REAL NOT NULL, tot_cost REAL NOT NULL, '\
              'pur_date TEXT NOT NULL, fab_date TEXT, due_date TEXT')
```

And I get this error:

```
  File "app.py", line 17, in create_tables
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sells(cod INTEGER NOT NULL, bar_code INTEGER, '\
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

I have no idea why this happens, because the first table is created with no problems (I already commented the two others and the script ran normally). Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You have one parenthesis missing in your second SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket in your second and third table inserts:

```
def create_tables():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(cod INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, bar_code INTEGER, '\
              'descr VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, quant_stock REAL, type_un TEXT, cost_un REAL, value_un REAL NOT NULL, fab_date TEXT, '\
              'due_date TEXT)')

    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sells(cod INTEGER NOT NULL, bar_code INTEGER, '\
              'descr TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value_un REAL NOT NULL, type_un TEXT, quant_stock REAL NOT NULL, '\
              'tot_value REAL NOT NULL, sell_date TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (cod) REFERENCES products(cod))')

    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchase(cod INTEGER FOREIGN KEY, bar_code INTEGER, '\
              'descr TEXT NOT NULL, cost_un REAL, type_un TEXT, pur_quant REAL NOT NULL, tot_cost REAL NOT NULL, '\
              'pur_date TEXT NOT NULL, fab_date TEXT, due_date TEXT)')
```

Comment: Ouch! Such a little thing was killing me! Lol! Thanks!